# Getting Call to a member function query() on a non-object (PHP)

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new using PDO in PHP and I'd like a bit of help here:

I've created two class, the first has the conection to the database, and the second is the model.

The only thing I want to is print the elemets of the database, but I'm always getting the same error:

```
Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php

    class DBConnection {
        private $dbConnected;

        public function __construct() {
        }

        public function iniciarConexion() {
            $this->dbConnected = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', '123456');
        }

        public function cerrarConexion() {
            /* Write Something */
        }
    }

    class Sectores extends DBConnection {
        private $conexion;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->conexion = new DBConnection();
            $this->conexion->iniciarConexion();
        }

        public function ObtenerSectores() {
            $sql = "SELECT 'sector' FROM sector ORDER BY numero";
            $resultado = $this->conexion->iniciarConexion->query($sql);
            
            foreach ($resultado as $row) {
                print $row['numero'] . "\t";
                print $row['sector'] . "\t";
            }

        }
    }

    $Sectores = new Sectores();
    $Sectores->ObtenerSectores();

?>
```

By the way, the pgsql is working good, I've tested this already.

Comment: Be aware that you extend DBConnection. IMO there should not be a `private $conexion` because your new class already has that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the wrong variable. You extend the class DBConnection, so you already have its functionality by default.

```
class Sectores extends DBConnection {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->iniciarConexion();
    }

    public function ObtenerSectores() {
        $sql = "SELECT 'sector' FROM sector ORDER BY numero";
        $resultado = $this->dbConnected->query($sql);

        foreach ($resultado as $row) {
            print $row['numero'] . "\t";
            print $row['sector'] . "\t";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey dude, I'm very thankful for your answer, but now I have the following question: 

How Can I work now if I delete extends class?

I've added the DBConnection via include... But it doesn't work... How Can I solved it?

Comment: Not sure what your intention is. If you delete `extends DBConnection` from your class definition then you don't have that functionality in your class. You should make a `$dbconnection` variable and initiate that in your constructor. In you `DBConnection` class you should add a public function that returns you the `$dbConnected` variable. Or even better the query result directly.